# How to create this XML with Delphi 12?

Tags: xml, delphi

I want to write some code (in Delphi) to get this XML scheme. But I can't assign attributes to nodes <User1/> and <User2/>

```
<Project ProjectName="CoolProject">
 <Options Opt1="Some Options Attribute Value">
  <User1 User1Opt="Some User1 Attribute Value"/>
  <User2 User2Opt="Some User2 Attribute Value"/>
 </Options>
</Project>
```

My code is

```
Var
  XML : IXMLDOCUMENT;
  RootNode, CurNode : IXMLNODE;
begin
  XML := NewXMLDocument;
  XML.Encoding := 'utf-8';
  RootNode := XML.AddChild('Project');
  RootNode.Attributes['ProjectName'] := 'CoolProject';
  CurNode := RootNode.AddChild('Options');
  CurNode.Attributes['Opt1'] := 'Some Options Attribute Value';
  CurNode.AddChild('User1');
  CurNode.Attributes['User1Opt'] := 'Some User1 Attribute Value';
  CurNode.AddChild('User2');
  CurNode.Attributes['User2Opt'] := 'Some User2 Attribute Value';
  XML.SaveToFile('c:\test\test.xml');
end;
```

And the result I get is

```
<Project ProjectName="CoolProject">
 <Options Opt1="Some Options Attribute Value" User1Opt="Some User1 Attribute Value" User2Opt="Some User2 Attribute Value">
  <User1/>
  <User2/>
 </Options>
</Project>
```

Comment: To me, it seems like the computer is doing exactly what you tell it to do, isn't it? (Hint: What is `CurNode` at each line?)

Comment: `CurNode.AddChild` -> `CurNode := CurNode.AddChild`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you have made a simple mistake that you immediately recognise when we point it out to you. Instead of this:

```
CurNode.AddChild('User1');
CurNode.Attributes['User1Opt'] := 'Some User1 Attribute Value';
```

You need to write this:

```
User1Node := CurNode.AddChild('User1');
User1Node.Attributes['User1Opt'] := 'Some User1 Attribute Value';
```

And similarly for the User2 node.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But in this case, I will not get the necessary structure, User2 will be placed in User1:
'<Project ProjectName="CoolProject">
<Options Opt1="Some Options Attribute Value">
<User1 User1Opt="Some User1 Attribute Value">
<User2 User2Opt="Some User2 Attribute Value"/>
</User1>
</Options>
</Project>'

Comment: Oh, indeed, that's right. Anyway, the general idea is clear, I hope: you need to call .AddChild on the right parent node, and then (if needed) store the returned new child node in a variable of your choice, if you need to use that as a parent for something else.

Comment: @MatthiasB don't give up so easily. Now you know the general issue, work the rest out yourself.

Comment: I found a solution thanks to your tips ))